# Firefox 20 vs Google charts - getValue oddness

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, google-visualization

Well here's an odd one...

The code snippet below is working perfectly in Chrome, IE8 and Safari. Until last week (I'm told by users...) it was working in Firefox.

It's no longer working in FF 20.0.1

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(briefData);
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('masterstatus'));
chart.draw(data, options);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e){
  if (chart.getSelection()[0].column && chart.getSelection()[0].row >=0){
    status = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0);
    makeOwnerTable(status);
  }
});
```

Not a lot of point in posting any more code - it's mostly context specific stuff - hundreds of lines of limited (I think) relevance.

Bottom line is that page displays two google charts, a bar chart and table chart - the table chart is refreshed based on the user clicking a bar in the barchart

Symptoms...

The makeOwnerTable function is receiving an empty string in FF. putting a breakpoint in firebug at the

```
makeOwnerTable(status);
```

line, confirms that the var status = "" (the same breakpoint in Chrome dev tools gives status="foo"). Entering

```
x = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0)
```

at the Firebug prompt while the script is paused gives me x = "foo".

Now normally when this kind of oddness goes on I go looking for feral ajax stuff that hasn't finished, but that's not the case here.

So.. to sum up...
In FF 20.0.1 (and only FF 20.0.1) Google's getValue appears not to work at runtime but does work at the FB prompt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "status" isn't declares as a var.  So that's setting `window.status`.  And that happens to not work in Firefox 20 (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=862540 ).

I recommend putting "var" before that status variable, so it's a function local.

Comment: Thanks Boris! That fixed it (I actually changed the var name away from status to avoid confusion in the future)